# commitlint config-conventional - Add prefix for commit messages

Tags: node.js, git, github, github-actions

I am trying to implement **commitlint** for one of my repo so all the commit messages are standard. However, we have requirement to ADD JIRA ID as part of prefix.

currently, commitlint format is as below

```
subject(scope): message
```

I need as mentioned below

```
JIRA-ID: subject(scope): message
```

following works

```
parserPreset: {
    parserOpts: {
         issuePrefixes: ['w{2,4}-[0.9]{2,4}']
    }
}
```

However it validates that JIRA id should be at the end. someething like below

```
subject(scope): message JIRA-ID
```

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Sames question here!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package https://github.com/Gherciu/commitlint-jira it works good out of the box with Jira commits style ;)

For Tips and [Advanced Usage](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-write-correct-jira-commit-messages-d9910f332273) you can read this [Blog Post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-write-correct-jira-commit-messages-d9910f332273)

Comment: Can I configure that it will search the JIRA ID in entire message and not just beginning of string?

Answer (score 0):

The default header shape is as follows ([docs ref](https://commitlint.js.org/#/reference-configuration?id=parser-presets)):

```
module.exports = {
  parserOpts: {
    headerPattern: /^(\w*)\((\w*)\)-(\w*)\s(.*)$/,
    headerCorrespondence: ['type', 'scope', 'ticket', 'subject'],
  },
};
```

You can set the header with any other shape you need, for example:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],
  rules: {
    'type-empty': [2, 'always'],
    'scope-empty': [2, 'always'],
  },
  parserPreset: {
    parserOpts: {
      headerPattern: /^(JIRA-[0-9]{2,4}):(.+)$/,
      headerCorrespondence: ['ticket', 'subject'],
    }
  }
};
```